# Proving by induction that $n^2 - 7n - 2$ is divisible by $2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

Now proving by induction is fairly simple. However, this is a multiple choice problem whose answers don't make any sense to me. The actual problem goes as follows:

*To prove by induction that $n^2 - 7n - 2$ is divisible by $2$ is true for all  positive integers $n$, we assume $k^2 - 7k - 2$ is divisible by $2$ is true for some positive integers $k$ and we show that $k^2 - 7k - 2 + A$ is divisible by $2$ where $A$ is:*

Now I would've assumed that $A$ would be $(k+1)^2 - 7(k + 1) - 2$, but I checked the answer and it is actually $2(k-3)$ which makes no sense to me. I tried to factor, reduce, and anything I could think of but I can't get $(k+1)^2 - 7(k + 1) - 2$. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: This seems like an idiotic problem (not OP's fault). It's like someone tried to make an induction problem, a notoriously difficult proof technique for beginners, even harder by requiring the answer for an ultimately irrelevant detail.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**: For the inductive step, we assume that $2$ divides $n^2-7n-2$, i.e., $n^2-7n-2 = 2M$. We now have
\begin{align}
(n+1)^2 - 7(n+1) - 2 & = n^2 + 2n + 1 - 7n - 7 +2 = n^2 - 7n -2 + 2(n-3)\\
& = 2(M+n-3)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that
$$ n^2 - 7n - 2  - ( (n-1)^2 - 7(n-1) - 2)) 
= 2n - 1 - 7 = 2(n-4).$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $ $ If $\,f(0)\,$ is even and $\,f(n\!+\!1)-f(n)=2j\,$ is even then by induction $\,f(n)\,$ is even for all $\,n,\,$ the inductive step being: $\ \,f(n+1) = f(n) +2j = $ even + even = even.

**Remark** $\ $ mod $\,2\,$ it is simply: $ $ if $f\,$ is constant $\,f(n\!+\!1)\equiv f(n)\,$ then $\,f(n)\equiv f(0)\,$ for all $\,n$.

Answer (score 0):

In the problem statement *"we show that $k^2 - 7k - 2 + A$ is divisible by $2\dots$"*. I think that what is intended here is that $k^2 - 7k - 2 + A$ is the next case. In other words
$$k^2 - 7k - 2 + A = (k+1)^2 -7(k+1)-2$$
Do the math, and I'm sure that you'll come up with
$$A = 2(k-3)$$
To finish off the problem, show that
$$k^2 - 7k - 2 + \color{blue}{2(k-3)} = (k+1)^2 -7(k+1)-2$$